# FullCalendar un dia antes de lo especificado

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Cuando coloco una fecha de inicio y una final, entonces se coloca un dia antes, por ejemplo: **2017-12-01** a **2017-12-03** me pone un dia antes **2017-12-02** estoy utilizando moment.js y este es el formato que tengo

```
moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Publica el Código Para Poder ayudarte

Comment: No coloques frases como: `ayuda!!!` en un lugar cuya unica razon de existir es eso. El titulo debe ser objetivo y sencillo.

Answer (score 0):

Full Calendar utiliza las propiedades 'start' y 'end' de los eventos para establecer el tiempo que éstos ocuparan a lo largo del tiempo.

El la fecha y hora que colorarás en la propiedad 'end' no es inclusive.

```js
events: [
  {
    title : "Mi evento",
    start : "2017-12-12 00:00:00",
    end   : "2017-12-13 00:00:00"
  }
]
```

Este evento se mostrará exclusivamente durante el día 12 de diciembre.   Para que pudiera también desplegarse a lo largo del día 13 tendrías que:

```js
events: [
  {
    title : "Mi evento",
    start : "2017-12-12 00:00:00",
    end   : "2017-12-14 00:00:00"  //aumentar un día a la fecha
  }
]
```

El segundo evento se muestra los días 12 y 13 de diciembre porque el valor de la propuedad 'end' de "2017-12-14 00:00:00" (que corresponde al 14 de diciembre), no es inclusive.

Por otra parte está padrísimo Full Calendar.  Después de buscar y buscar no lo cambiaría por otra opción.   Te recomiendo que te metas a los ejemplos que se incluyen en la descarga.  Chécalos cómo se ven y luego observa el código.  Es muy amigable.

Comment: Pero si el usuario quiere crear un evento del 12 al 13, por que no me sale en el calendario asi, sino que me sale un solo dia que es el 12 y no mas, o tengo que poner alguna alerta para decirle al usuario que elija un dia de mas????

start : "2017-12-12 00:00:00",
end   : "2017-12-13 00:00:00"


Solo funciona cuando pongo una hora a la propiedad END ejemplo:

start : "2017-12-12 00:00:00",
end   : "2017-12-13 24:00:00"

Pero si pongo otra hora a la propiedad END 
start : "2017-12-12 00:00:00",
end   : "2017-12-13 08:15:00"

me da un dia menos otra vez :(

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el javascript y si tenes

```
$('#cal-basic').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start._d,
                        end: end._d,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true
                    );
YO lo soluciones sacandole "._d"
$('#cal-basic').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true
                    );
```